# Facebook Audience Network Interstitial Impressions to Filled

Tags: android, facebook, interstitial, facebook-audience-network

My app runs a full interstitial on open of our app, which is powered by the Facebook Audience Network, we have a very high request to filled ration (90%) but we have a very low filled to impressions (30%).

How is this possible since it is a full screen interstitial, shouldn't it be 1:1 since the whole ad will be viewable?

Every time I test the app the ads work fine with test tokens.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about ad network behavior, not programming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question

Answer (score 2):

The ratio between filled and impression can often not be 1:1 for several reasons. Interstitials are first requested, and then shown. If there is a drop off between these two steps then it can lead to you having a higher number of filled requests than impressions.

For example, if you request an interstitial at the start of a level in a game, and show it after the game over screen, then any drop off of users before this screen will cause a difference in the filled to impression metrics.